# Reuse an stream in esper in several queries

Tags: java, esper

I'm trying to use [EsperIO](http://www.espertech.com/esper/release-5.5.0/esperio-reference/html_single/index.html#adapterdb-gettingstarted-API) to load some information from database and use it in other queries with different conditions. To do it I'm using the following code:

```
    ConfigurationDBRef dbConfig = new ConfigurationDBRef();
    dbConfig.setDriverManagerConnection("org.postgresql.Driver",
                     "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/myDatabase",
                     "myUser", "myPassword");

    Configuration engineConfig = new Configuration();
    engineConfig.addDatabaseReference("myDatabase", dbConfig);

    // Custom class
    engineConfig.addEventType("UserFromDB", UserDB.class);

    EPServiceProvider esperEngine = EPServiceProviderManager.getDefaultProvider(engineConfig);

    String statement =  "insert into UserFromDB "
                      + "   select * from sql:myDatabase ['SELECT * from data.user']";

    //Install this query in the engine
    EPStatement queryEngineObject = esperEngine.getEPAdministrator().createEPL(statement);

    // 1. At this point I can iterate over queryEngineObject without problems getting the information sent by database

    // This query is only a 'dummy example', the 'final queries' are more complex
    statement = "select * from UserFromDB";
    EPStatement queryEngineObject2 = esperEngine.getEPAdministrator().createEPL(statement);

    // 2. If I try to iterate over queryEngineObject2 I receive no data
```

How can I reuse **UserFromDB** stored information in other queries? (in the above example, in *queryEngineObject2*)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a stream since the database doesn't provide a stream. The database query provides rows only when its being iterated/pulled.
One option is to loop over each row and send it into the engine using "sendEvent":

```
// create other EPL statements before iterating
Iterator<EventBean> it = statement.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
  epService.getEPRuntime().sendEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my error in this case is that I "forgot" to include listeners to manage the results of the second statement. It is not possible to do it using another for/while loop and iterate through the second sentence directly.